# Как отправить CSV файл приложенным к письму

Tags: java, android

имеется файл `out.csv`.

как отправить его приложенным к письму через emailIntent?

Comment: А чем csv-файл отличается от любого другого?

Comment: я немного запутался в коде котором вы отправили, у меня 1 файл и он создается автоматически и хранится по пути "//data/data/com.test.mytest/files/outTask.csv" мне нужно его отправить после создания по почте, но почему то не получается